# How can I make a pointer that points to a pointer, but only to half of the future result, which is contained in a pointer that points to a result?

Tags: c++, pointers, z3

Full question is:

How can I make a pointer that points to a pointer, but only to half of the future result, which in turn is contained in a pointer that points to a result (which is not there yet, but it will be in the future)?

### Introduction:

I'm working with z3 and I made the following code:

```
class x8664_ctx
{
public:
    z3::expr* rax;
    z3::expr* rbx;
    z3::expr* r8;
    inline x8664_ctx()
        : rax(nullptr)
        , rbx(nullptr)
        , r8(nullptr)
    {}
```

Next I initialize them as bv_const for z3

```
inline void create_initial_state(z3::context& z3c, x8664_ctx& ctx)
{
    ctx.rax = new z3::expr(z3c.bv_const("init_rax", 64));
    ctx.rbx = new z3::expr(z3c.bv_const("init_rbx", 64));
    ctx.r8 = new z3::expr(z3c.bv_const("init_r8", 64));
}
```

And I translate similar mnemonic to z3

```
static inline void translate_mov(
    z3::context& z3c, 
    x8664_ctx& old_state, 
    x8664_ctx& new_state, 
    ZydisDisassembledInstruction ins)
{
    if (ins.info.operand_count_visible == 2)
    {
        auto& op1 = ins.operands[0];
        auto& op2 = ins.operands[1];

        z3::expr e2 = **Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::get_val_expr(z3c, old_state, op2);
        z3::expr** dst = Z3SystemTranslateFuncs::get_val_expr(z3c, new_state, op1);
        
        *dst = new z3::expr(z3c, e2);

    }
    else
        throw std::exception("bad operand count in translate_mov func");
}
```

### Main problem:

I have a function that finds out which register is in the operand and whether there is a register at all, and my task is to get *al* and *bl* and *r8b*, etc. the lower parts of my registers.
This function:

```
namespace Z3SystemTranslateFuncs {

    static inline z3::expr** get_val_expr(
        z3::context& z3c, 
        x8664_ctx& state, 
        ZydisDecodedOperand op)
    {
        if (op.type == ZYDIS_OPERAND_TYPE_REGISTER)
        {
            z3::expr** ret;
            //z3::expr* r8b = new z3::expr (state.r8->extract(7, 0));

            //z3::expr* r8b_ = &state.r8->extract(7,0);
            switch (op.reg.value)
            {
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_RAX: return ret = &state.rax;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_EAX: return ret = &state.rax;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_AX: return ret = &state.rax;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_AH: return ret = &state.rax;
            //case ZYDIS_REGISTER_AL: al = &al_; return ret = &al;

            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_RBX: return ret = &state.rbx;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_EBX: return ret = &state.rbx;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_BX: return ret = &state.rbx;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_BH: return ret = &state.rbx;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_BL: return ret = &state.rbx;

            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_R8: return ret = &state.r8;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_R8D: return ret = &state.r8;
            case ZYDIS_REGISTER_R8W: return ret = &state.r8;
            //case ZYDIS_REGISTER_R8B: return ret = &state.r8;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case(`z3::expr* r8b = new z3::expr (state.r8->extract(7, 0));`), and in this case(`z3::expr* r8b_ = &state.r8->extract(7,0);`), I get an error z3 on getting a number by the extract method, since bv_const r8 itself or the like. the variable is initialized, but not involved and it does not contain anything else (but it will be later). So the main question is how can I get the lower part of this variable z3, given that it is not yet involved but will be involved here: `*dst = new z3::expr(z3c, e2);` or in similar places of other mnemonics.

Thanks in advance to all those who will take the time for minimal help or tell me where I can start solving this problem!

### P.S.

the extract method returns any part of the variable, for example R8 == 0x7B4D6D3000, then ...extract(7, 0) will give 00, and ...extract(15, 8) will give 30, and ...extract(31, 0) will give 4D6D3000

Comment: It is not possible to create a pointer to (part of) something that does not yet exist.

Comment: hmm okay. I got you @Peter

Comment: But I have it and at the same time I don't. I do not know how to explain it, but I have the variables themselves, but as if they are not there for me yet...

Comment: Bit brainstorming here : why do you even use pointers in your  `x8664_ctx` struct (lack of default constructor for z3::expr?). Either give your x8664_ctx struct a constructor that can initialize your `z3::expr` directly or use `std::unique_ptr<z3::expr>` . And get_val_expr should return a `z3::expr&` with eg `return *state.r8;` (assuming state.rbx and state.r8 etc all have the same type)